# Does @username-san work in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

When doing a comment, should `@username-san` notify the user that they've been replied to?

Someone recently `@AndrewGrimm-san`'d me, and I didn't get notified of it.

Comment: I would rather use a space instead of a hyphen to make it work.

Comment: Or you could use a space then a hyphen...I think that might work (@Andrew -san?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for this are quite complicated. In particular to this case see rules 3 and 9.

From 3: In most (all?) cases including `-san` will mean that the name is not matched and the user is not notified.

From 9: If the comment was edited to include your name in certain circumstances you might not be notified.